# Oracle SQL WHERE MONTH = N

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In my select I am using this

```
(TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, 'dd.mm.yyyyHH24:mi'))) TIMESTAMP,
```

to get the following output in a date format: e.g. `22/04/2016`

Now I want to add a statement in my WHERE-clause to show only dates in special months, for example only dates which are in MARCH and APRIL

I tried using this:

```
WHERE (TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, 'mm'))) in (3,4)
```

which gives me an error.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It usually helps to say *what* error you get. `TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, ...)` is converting your timestamp to a string using your NLS settings and then trying to convert that string back to a date with an inappropriate mask. You probably meant to use `TO_CHAR()`, but then the `TRUNC()` wouldn't be right either.. Your first expression is wrong too, that should also use `TO_CHAR()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my select I am using this
>
> ```
> (TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, 'dd.mm.yyyyHH24:mi'))) TIMESTAMP,
> ```
>
> to get the following output in a date format: e.g. `22/04/2016`

`TO_DATE` takes a string value so your `"TIMESTAMP"` column will be implicitly converted to a string and then back to a date... which is unnecessary (and relies on the value of the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter to format the implicit conversion - which, if changed, will break the query); you can just do:

```
TRUNC( "TIMESTAMP" ) AS "TIMESTAMP"
```

If you want to then filter on different months then you can do (as suggested by Tim Biegeleisen):

```
WHERE EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "TIMESTAMP" ) IN ( 3, 4 )
```

or if you want a particular year then

```
WHERE TRUNC( "TIMESTAMP", 'MM' ) IN ( DATE '2016-03-01', DATE '2016-04-01' )
```

or, so you can use an index on the column:

```
WHERE "TIMESTAMP" >= DATE '2016-03-01'
AND   "TIMESTAMP" <  DATE '2016-05-01'
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `EXTRACT()` on the timestamp:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) IN (3, 4)
```

This would match records from March and April.